# dmidecode -s system-version command return not specified error

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to get some system information from my computer, and I wrote `sudo dmidecode -s system-version` in the Terminal, but am receiving a `Not Specified` error:

[image: Screenshot of Error]

How can I read my system information?

Comment: You can always run `man dmidecode` to learn more about the syntax and all available command options.

Comment: This generally means that the computer manufacturer did not set a value for `system-version` in the DMI table. Using just `sudo dmidecode` by itself will give you a full list of the structures available for reading.

Comment: but I want only `system-version` not want all information, comp: dell latitude

Comment: If your BIOS does not hold the version dmidecode can not provide it. You would need to update your BIOS with a version that does, if that is possible.